# How to highlight a row in ListView when a data value is low

Tags: mysql, vb.net, listview

What I want to happen is that when the `Quantity` on an item in a `ListView` is less than 10, the row's backcolor will change. My code below only changes the back color of the last row. Please help.

```
   Dim list1 As New ListViewItem()
   Dim blank As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
   Dim product As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

   Private Sub LoadDatabase()
      productReport.Items.Clear()
      command.CommandText = "SELECT Product_Code, Product_Name, Quantity, Unit, Category, Location, Description FROM tblProduct"
      command.Connection = connect
      adapter.SelectCommand = command
      reader = command.ExecuteReader()
      While reader.Read
          list1 = productReport.Items.Add(reader.GetString(0))
          list1.SubItems.Add(reader.GetString(1))
          list1.SubItems.Add(reader.GetString(2))
          list1.SubItems.Add(reader.GetString(3))
          list1.SubItems.Add(reader.GetString(4))
          list1.SubItems.Add(reader.GetString(5))
          list1.SubItems.Add(reader.GetString(6))
          quantity.Add(reader.GetValue(2))
          blank.Add(reader.GetString(4))
      End While
   reader.Close()
   End Sub

   Public Sub viewCritical()
            Dim a = productReport.Items.Count
            For x As Integer = 0 To productReport.Items.Count - 1
                a = a - 1
                If (quantity.Item(a) < 15) Then
                    list1.SubItems(a).BackColor = Color.LightCoral
                    Label1.Show()
                End If
                If (blank.Item(a) = "") Then
                    list1.SubItems(a).BackColor = Color.LightGreen
                    Label3.Show()
                End If
            Next
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, all subitems use the same forecolor/backcolor/font.

To allow each subitem to have it's own properties, you need to set `ListViewItem.UseItemStyleForSubItems` to `false`.